# Why does this element in lxml include the tail?

Tags: python, html, lxml

Consider this Python script:

```
from lxml import etree

html = '''
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
  <body>
    <p>This is some text followed with 2 citations.<span class="footnote">1</span>
       <span сlass="footnote">2</span>This is some more text.</p>
  </body>
</html>'''

tree = etree.fromstring(html)

for element in tree.findall(".//{*}span"):
    if element.get("class") == 'footnote':
        print(etree.tostring(element, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

The desired output would be the 2 `span` elements, instead I get:

```
<span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="footnote">1</span>
<span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="footnote">2</span>This is some more text.
```

Why does it include the text after the element until the end of the parent element?

I'm trying to use lxml to link footnotes and when I `a.insert()` the `span` element into the `a` element I create for it, it's including the text after and so linking large amounts of text I don't want linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying `with_tail=False` will remove the tail text.

```
print(etree.tostring(element, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True, with_tail=False))
```

See [`lxml.etree.tostring` documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring).

Answer (score 2):

It includes the text after the element, because that text belongs to the element.

If you don't want that text to belong to the previous span, it needs to be contained in it's own element. However, you can avoid printing this text when converting the element back to XML with `with_tail=False` as a parameter to `etree.tostring()`.

You can also simply set the elements tail to `''` if you want to remove it from a specific element.

Comment: I would have thought the text would belong to the `p` element that contains the `span`? The text is completely outside of the `span` element.

Comment: @BigJord Yes, it's outside, that's why it called a **tail**. It can't belong to the P element, as it would clash with the first text; `This is some text followed with 2 citations.`

Comment: I recently ran into this issue, and while this topic is older. It did help me understand. I will say that like the original poster, I didn't understand the reason I was getting text that belongs to to the <p> element. In fact, if you do this in any other xml parser/library this whole idea of tail doesn't exist. This is really a quirk in how the Python libraries seem to deal with text nodes. I ran my specific test using both Ruby and oXygen XML editor and both handled this correctly, but now that I understand this quirk in Python I can deal with it properly.

Comment: @WayneBrissette I don't know how other libraries store that data, but it needs to be stored somewhere. lxml puts it in the tail attribute. I guess an alternative would be to have text nodes?

Comment: @lennart: Here's the thing, according to how XML works, that part that lxml calls a tail, isn't that. It is by definition part of the <p> element that's where it belongs. Take out the child <span> from the tree and you should still have it as part of <p> (without having to fuss with the quirky .tail part). As somebody who came to python's XML for other languages this just seems a bit strange. No other libraries have this quirk, and that's why it bit me, and I'm sure others too coming from other implementations will find it a bit strange. Once you understand it, it's not a big deal however.